# MySQL: Sometimes DateTime being stored -12hrs

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

In our system (ASP.NET with a MySQL DB) we record several tens of orders each day. We also record several bills (of one or more orders) each day.

Both the Orders and Bills tables have a field `billed_date` (the field is identical in both tables).

When we record the creation of a bill we create a DateTime object in .NET, set the time to 00:00:00, then send it into MySQL as parameterised UPDATE and INSERT queries. The same DateTime object is used for updating the Orders table *and* inserting into the Bills table, and is not modified between the UPDATE and the INSERT.

Now here's the strange part: very occasionally (70 times in the past couple of years) a date shows up in the Orders table having had 12 hours deducted from it.

For example

```
Orders.billed_date = '2014-03-01 12:00:00'
Bills.billed_date = '2012-03-02 00:00:00'
```

The `billed-date` field in question (in both tables) is a nullable DateTime field with none of the options set (*i.e.*, PK, NN, UQ, BIN, UN, ZF and AI are all unchecked).

Can anyone explain why this happens, and why it happens only rarely?

Comment: Could you show the code that builds executes the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands?  Are you able to say whether the data is incorrect from the outset, or is it subsequently modified?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't paste in the code because there's just too much in the way of table names, etc., that I wouldn't be willing to broadcast here.  However - and I hope this answers your second question - we *don't believe* there are any subsequent queries that are modifying the suspicious dates; we believe that when we look at one of these 'wrong' dates we're looking at the value that was put there by the UPDATE query.

Comment: Why can't you show the `UPDATE` query with the table/column names changed?